# google app script Exceeded memory limit

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets, xml-parsing

May be this question already asked, but that won't solve my problem.

I try to save data's into `google spreadsheet` using `google app script`. But it shows Exceeded memory limit error.

following my code:

```
//new
function getNewTitle() {
    var url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/DigitalMarketing.rss?limit=100&after=0";
    var fromText = '</updated><title>';
    var toText = '</title>';
    var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();

    var scraped = Parser.data(content).from(fromText).to(toText).iterate();
    return scraped;
}

function getNewContent() {
    var url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/DigitalMarketing.rss?limit=10&after=0";
    var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();

    var document = XmlService.parse(content);
    var root = document.getRootElement();
    var atom = XmlService.getNamespace('http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
    Logger.log(atom);

    var fromText = '<content type="html">&lt;!-- SC_OFF --&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;md&quot;&gt;&lt;p&gt;';
    var toText = '</div>';


    var scraped = Parser.data(content).from(fromText).to(toText).iterate();

    return scraped;
}

function getNewLink() {
    var url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/DigitalMarketing.rss?limit=10&after=0";
    var fromText = '<link href="';
    var toText = '" /><updated>';
    var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();

    var scraped = Parser.data(content).from(fromText).to(toText).iterate();

    return scraped;
}

function SAVE_DATA() {
  var sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1No3m_FnhyxIaxj2zSlbHrg8HLBJULGQ2bda65hpKlyY').getSheetByName('sample'); 
 var content   = getNewContent();
  var title   = getNewTitle();
  var link   = getNewLink();
  Logger.log(title[1]);
  for(var i =0; i < title.length; i++) { 
    sheet.appendRow([ 'Reddit','wordpress', title[i], link[i], content[i]]);
  }
}
//new
```

In my above code am tried to save the data from `url`.

> But i get `Exceeded memory limit` error.

In my Log i got this message

> [18-07-21 05:33:29:719 PDT] [Namespace: prefix "" is mapped to URI "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"]

Please help me to fix this error...!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is this `Parser`

Comment: @I'-'I Actually i added `parser` in `Resources -> Library `

Comment: Sorry this is the 1st time am using `google app script`, i don't know how to solve this issue

Comment: Have to see what's going on inside `Parser` too. But,For starters, create a output array and Use `setValues()` instead of `appendRow()`. Also share your logs and execution transcripts. Was there any line written on the spreadsheet?

Comment: @I'-'I inside Parser i got this https://ibb.co/iVggTd

Comment: You didn't answer the rest of my questions. Especially [Edit] to include logs and execution transcripts,so that others might also help. Also know that there are [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations): Specifically URLFetch has 50MB/call. Try to debug and include all debugging details in the question.

Comment: Sounds like you need to work on a smaller link.

Comment: in my log i got this [18-07-21 05:21:04:644 PDT] [Namespace: prefix "" is mapped to URI "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"]

Comment: @I'-'I can i share my screen ?

Comment: @I'-'I question updated ..!

Comment: Yes post your screen in the question. Execution transcript too(should be in view). Post complete logs.

Comment: Have you tried reducing limit to `5` from `100`

Comment: @I'-'I I have tried with reducing limit to 5 from 100. But unfortunately its not working.. Shall I share my screen.

Comment: @I'-'I Parser is a GAS library. You can see this information at [here](https://www.kutil.org/2016/01/easy-data-scrapping-with-google-apps.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the reason of the error is that `</div>` of `var toText = '</div>';` is not included in `content` retrieved from `https://www.reddit.com/r/DigitalMarketing.rss?limit=10&after=0`. So how about this modification?

### Modification points :

- `</div>` of `var toText = '</div>';` is not included in `content`. So in this modification, I used `</content>`. Because you are using `'<content type="html">&lt;!-- SC_OFF --&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;md&quot;&gt;&lt;p&gt;'` for `fromText`.
- `setValues()` instead of `appendRow()` is used for putting the values.

  - You can see the difference of the cost between `setValues()` and `appendRow()` at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51113444/google-sheet-script-timeout-error/51113736#51113736).

### Modified script :

#### 1. For `getNewContent()`

Please modify from

From :

```
var toText = '</div>';
```

To :

```
var toText = '</content>';
```

#### 2. For `SAVE_DATA()`

Please modify as follows.

```
function SAVE_DATA() {
  var sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1No3m_FnhyxIaxj2zSlbHrg8HLBJULGQ2bda65hpKlyY').getSheetByName('sample');
  var content = getNewContent();
  var title   = getNewTitle();
  var link   = getNewLink();
  var values = title.map(function(e, i){return [e, link[i], content[i]]});
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

### Note :

- In this modification, I used `var toText = '</content>';` for `getNewContent()`. If you want to retrieve other range of the site, please modify this.
- About the URL, `limit=100` for the title is set. But `limit=10` is set for the link and content. So when the values are retrieved and put them to Spreadsheet, link and content become undefined from 11 row.

  - If you have already known this, please ignore this.

### Reference :

- [Easy data scraping with Google Apps Script in 5 minutes](https://www.kutil.org/2016/01/easy-data-scrapping-with-google-apps.html)

  - Parser is a GAS library. You can check at here.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bro.

Comment: @Ramesh S Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.