# Writing the result of getEditors and getViewers to Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to write some metadata from Drive files in a spreadsheet. I get the owner, name, Id, url, etc., but I'm having problems with the `File#getEditors()` and `File#getViewers()` methods.

I get this value written in the cells where the editors and viewers results are written:

> [Ljava.lang.Object@....

[image]
Anyone knows what is happening? I'm the owner of the files.

My script:

```
function getChildFolders(parentName, parent, data, sheet, listAll) {
  sheet.appendRow(["Full Path", "Name", "Type", "URL", "Access", "Permission", "Editors can share", "Owner", "Can edit", "Can comment", "Can view"]);

  var childFolders = parent.getFolders();
  var childFiles = parent.getFiles();

  while (childFiles.hasNext()) {
    var fileItem = childFiles.next();

    data = [
      parentName + "/" + fileItem.getName() + "/" + fileItem.getName(),
      fileItem.getName(),
      fileItem.getMimeType(),
      fileItem.getUrl(),
      fileItem.getAccess(Session.getActiveUser()),
      fileItem.getSharingPermission(),
      fileItem.isShareableByEditors(),
      fileItem.getOwner().getEmail(),
      fileItem.getEditors(),
      fileItem.getViewers()
    ];

    // Write      
    sheet.appendRow(data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[Ljava.lang.Object` means an object. `fileItem.getEditors()` and `fileItem.getViewers()` are objects. Each object returns `User[]`. You can retrieve the following values from it.

- `getDomain()`: Gets the domain name associated with the user's account.
- `getEmail()`: Gets the user's email address.
- `getName()`: Gets the user's name.
- `getPhotoUrl()`: Gets the URL for the user's photo.

So for example, if emails and names of editors and viewers are retrieved, how about this modification?

#### Modified script :

Please modify as follows.

From :

```
fileItem.getEditors(),
fileItem.getViewers()
```

To :

```
fileItem.getEditors().map(function(e){return [e.getEmail(), e.getName()]}).join(","),
fileItem.getViewers().map(function(e){return [e.getEmail(), e.getName()]}).join(","),
```

#### Note :

- This is a sample. So please modify this for your situation.

#### References :

- [What does "[Ljava.lang.Object;@" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582248/what-does-ljava-lang-object-mean)
- [getEditors()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#geteditors)
- [getViewers()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getviewers)
- [Class User](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/user)

If this was not what you want, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

### Added :

This is a sample modified script using `setValues()` instead of `appendRow()`. The cost of `setValues()` is lower than that of `appendRow()`. So also how about this modification?

```
sheet.appendRow(["Full Path", "Name", "Type", "URL", "Access", "Permission", "Editors can share", "Owner", "Can edit", "Can comment", "Can view"]);
var childFolders = parent.getFolders();
var childFiles = parent.getFiles();
var allValues = []; // Added
while (childFiles.hasNext()){
  var fileItem = childFiles.next();
  data = [
    parentName + "/" + fileItem.getName() + "/" + fileItem.getName(),
    fileItem.getName(),
    fileItem.getMimeType(),
    fileItem.getUrl(),
    fileItem.getAccess(Session.getActiveUser()),
    fileItem.getSharingPermission(),
    fileItem.isShareableByEditors(),
    fileItem.getOwner().getEmail(),
    fileItem.getEditors().map(function(e){return [e.getEmail(), e.getName()]}).join(","),
    fileItem.getViewers().map(function(e){return [e.getEmail(), e.getName()]}).join(","),
  ];
  allValues.push(data); // Added
}
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, allValues.length, allValues[0].length).setValues(allValues); // Added
```

#### Reference :

- [Google sheet script timeout error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51113444/google-sheet-script-timeout-error/51113736#51113736)

Comment: Thank you so much! I 've done a 5-line script to solve it 3 mins ago, but this is much better. It works perfectly!

Comment: @Juan Bravo Roig Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was solved. As an additional sample, I added a sample modified script. How about that modification? The cost of ``setValues()`` is lower than that of ``appendRow()``. I'm not sure whether this additional modification is useful for you. So if this is not useful for your situation, please ignore it.